# Define ListenerContainer without the jms namespace in spring jms

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I want to assign an id to jms:listener-container bean but unfortunately it does not have an id property. For instance, this does not work

```
<jms:listener-container  id="jmsListenerContainer"  concurrency="${jms.consumer.concurrency}"  >
    <jms:listener id="queueHandler" destination="${jms.queue.name}" ref="queueListener" />
</jms:listener-container>
```

To counter that, I am trying to define the container without the namespace using vanilla bean definition, like so:

```
<bean id="jmsListenerContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer"  
    p:concurrency="${jms.consumer.concurrency}" p:connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory" 
    p:messageListener-ref="jmsMessageListener">
</bean>
```

For this to work one needs the actual implementation class of MessageListener used by the container as defining this separately does not work

```
<jms:listener id="jmsMessageListener" destination="${jms.queue.name}" ref="queueListener" />
```

This throws an `The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'jms:listener'.`

From documentation of AbstractMessageListenerContainer: `By default, only a standard JMS MessageListener object or a Spring SessionAwareMessageListener object will be accepted.`

This is quite inconclusive, so does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to propose an answer to my own question. The default listener class created with `jms:listener` is `org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter`

Here's the complete vanilla replacement of jms namespace based configuration:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter" id="jmsMessageListener" 
    p:delegate-ref="queueListener" />

<!-- Not using jms namespace, as it doesn't allow to specify bean id -->
<bean id="jmsListenerContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer"  
    p:concurrency="${jms.consumer.concurrency}" p:connection-factory-ref="jmsConnectionFactory" 
    p:messageListener-ref="jmsMessageListener" p:destinationName="${jms.queue.name}" >
</bean>
```